# Appending data to a Google Sheet from C# called SqlCommand

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api

I started with the basics and learned how to insert a fixed bit of rows to a Google Sheet from my program now I've been trying to figure out how to append output from a SQL. I have a C# program that calls a stored procedure or it can do a `select * from table`. Simply trying to insert the results/output of that select into a Google Sheet. Every example I find is dealing with hard coded fixed rows and columns. My select produces less than 2000 lines of output. Appreciate the help!

```
namespace CS_Gsheet1
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        //static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        //static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        static string ApplicationName = "Test3"; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = AuthorizeGoogleApp();

            String spreadsheetId = "sheetIDstring"; 

            // Write to specified sheet
            String writeRange = "Sheet1!A1:K";
            ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange { MajorDimension = "ROWS" };

            IList<object> dataList = new List<object>();

            using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedproc-selectsmultiplecolumnsandrows", myConnection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // dataList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                            // dataList.Add(reader.GetValue(0));
                            IList<IList<Object>> values = new List<IList<Object>>();
                            values.Add(dataList);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
            ValueRange valueDataRange = new ValueRange() { MajorDimension = "ROWS" };

            valueDataRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { dataList };

            int c = dataList.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("dataList Count {0}", c);

            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                // API to append data to sheet
                SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueDataRange, spreadsheetId, writeRange);
                appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
                appendRequest.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS;
                AppendValuesResponse appendValueResponse = appendRequest.Execute();
            }
        }

        private static SheetsService AuthorizeGoogleApp()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

                // Create Google Sheets API service.
                var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                return service;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider breaking your problem down into component parts. You want to get data from SQL, that should be its own method. Once you have that data, you want to use it to update your google sheet, which should be another method. This separates the problem into two mapping problems which are relatively easy to solve in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tweak this solution to get the process to work without requesting a quota increase from Google. It does not run very fast, but ok for ~1000 records.

https://github.com/jeffcrowder/GoogleSheetsAPIExample/blob/master/GoogleSheetsAPIExample/Program.cs